# How to observe network change in real time

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-view

Hello i have a simple app what i have done is when user is no connected to the internet while launchng the app it will show a text view "No Internet " but the issue is when i start the internet or connect to any netwrok it doesnt brings up the orignal view what i have to do is i close the app and open once again to bring the main view

how can i switch between this two views in realtime when the connection is on/off

**onCreate**

```
  // Internet on/off
        if (isOnline()) {
            noInternet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Online
            mainRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            noInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Disconnected
            mainRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

---

this is what im using currently get the connction info

```
 // Internet on/off
    public boolean isOnline() {
        boolean connected = false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
            return connected;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connected;
    }
```

Comment: You want something to observe the connection change and change your view accordingly right?

Comment: yes correct thats what i want

Comment: Great, I'll answer this in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To observe the connection changes in real time you can use LiveData. Before this we used BroadcastReceiver, but as you can see `Declaring a broadcastreceiver for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is deprecated for apps targeting N and higher.`

I'll post the full code and explain every part of it.

```
public class ConnectionLiveData extends LiveData<Boolean> {
    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;
    private final ConnectivityManager cm;
    private final HashSet<Network> validNetworks = new HashSet<>();
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_POST_DELAY = 1000;

 public ConnectionLiveData(Context context) {
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

private void checkValidNetworks() {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() ->
                    postValue(validNetworks.size() > 0),
            NETWORK_STATUS_POST_DELAY);
}

@Override
protected void onActive() {
    networkCallback = createNetworkCallback();
    NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .build();
    cm.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    cm.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
}

private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback createNetworkCallback() {
    return new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        /*
        Called when a network is detected. If that network has internet, save it in the Set.
        Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onAvailable(android.net.Network)
        */
        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
            boolean hasInternetCapability = capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
            if (hasInternetCapability) {
                // check if this network actually has internet
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    boolean hasInternet = DoesNetworkHaveInternet.execute(network.getSocketFactory());
                    if (hasInternet) {
                        validNetworks.add(network);
                        checkValidNetworks();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        /*
        If the callback was registered with registerNetworkCallback() it will be called for each network which no longer satisfies the criteria of the callback.
        Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onLost(android.net.Network)
        */
        @Override
        public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {
            validNetworks.remove(network);
            checkValidNetworks();
        }
    };
}
```

}

We extend `LiveData` here and implement 2 functions: `onActive()` and `onInactive()`. As you know `LiveData` is lifecycle-aware, when there is one observer, the `onActive` will be called. I use them to register/unregister the `ConnectivityManager`.
When we register our `ConnectivityManager` we pass a `networkCallback` as a parameter. It has several methods, but as you can see in the `createNetworkCallback()` function we override only `onAvailable()` and `onLost()` functions. The `onAvailable()` and `onLost()` will be called if you will switch your network on/off.

There may be a case when the connection is on, but there's no connection with the server. In this case, I found a simple class that we can use to ping and validate our connection.
Using `ExecutorService` I validate the internet connection by pinging.

```
boolean hasInternet = DoesNetworkHaveInternet.execute(network.getSocketFactory());
```

The `DoesNetworkHaveInternet` code:

```
public class DoesNetworkHaveInternet {

private static final String HOST_NAME = "8.8.8.8";
private static final int PORT = 53;
private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 1500;

@WorkerThread
static Boolean execute(SocketFactory socketFactory) {
    try {
        Socket socket = socketFactory.createSocket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST_NAME, PORT), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        socket.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

It's pinging and validates that we have a stable connection.
In the end, after verifying that we have a connection, we call the `checkValidNetworks()` functions. There is a delay because in some cases your connection may be off and on for a moment and for that I found there's no need to show network error. The `checkValidNetworks()` checks if `validNetworks` is not empty. It is a list as there are some types of connections, like wifi and mobile networks. If there's at least one stable connection, the `validNetworks` will not be empty.
That's it. You can observe it in your fragment or in an activity like this:

```
ConnectionLiveDataJava connectionLiveData = new ConnectionLiveDataJava(this);
connectionLiveData.observe(this, isConnected -> {
            
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for the code but its kotlin , please can u share java code

Comment: Sorry man, I don't have the Java version of it. Can you try to translate the code from kotlin to Java?

Comment: i dont understand what you are telling me to do

Comment: @Player91 I've updated the code from Kotlin to Java. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm inserting your code also put snackbar in my existing project.but two situation is happen

1. when every activity starts it snackbar shows.how to stop only first activity show others not.
2. if internet is not connected at the very first run. It show no snackbar.
   Please look at this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).